# Speed up integer encoding of strings in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as follows, consisting of string values.

```
    0   1   2
0   o   jj  ovg
1   j   jj  jjy
2   y   yk  yku
3   v   vf  vfs
4   i   iw  iwd
```

I have a function which encodes each column with integer values, and counts the number of unique elements in each column. I used `cat.codes` and `nunique` functions of `pandas`. See below the timing results and the code snippets.

As is evident, these operations take a lot of time. How can I speed them up?

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time         Line Contents
=====================================================================================================================
25           1    7529434.0   7529434.0     79.9      df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype('category').cat.codes)
26                                               
27                                                    # calculate the number of unique keys for each row
28           1    1825214.0   1825214.0     19.4      len_arr = df.nunique(axis=0).values
```

**Edit** Timing results from the answer

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
#100 loops, best of 3: 6.24 ms per loop
%timeit df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
#100 loops, best of 3: 4.93 ms per loop

%timeit df1.nunique(axis=0).values
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.34 ms per loop
%timeit df1.apply(lambda x: len(pd.factorize(x)[1]))
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.64 ms per loop
```

**Edit 2**
More timing results for fun:

```
# results with 100 rows
%timeit original()
#100 loops, best of 3: 7 ms per loop
%timeit WeNYoBen()
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.4 ms per loop
%timeit jezrael()
#100 loops, best of 3: 4.03 ms per loop
%timeit piRSquared()
#100 loops, best of 3: 2.29 ms per loop

# results with 10000 rows
%timeit original()
#100 loops, best of 3: 16.6 ms per loop
%timeit WeNYoBen()
#10 loops, best of 3: 23 ms per loop
%timeit jezrael()
#100 loops, best of 3: 6.14 ms per loop
%timeit piRSquared()
#100 loops, best of 3: 19.1 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html) with length of second array:

```
a = df.apply(lambda x: len(pd.factorize(x)[1]))
print (a)
0    5
1    4
2    5
dtype: int64
```

For integers:

```
b = df.apply(lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0])
print (b)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1
2  2  1  2
3  3  2  3
4  4  3  4
```

All together for avoid call function twice:

```
out = {}
def f(x):
    a, b = pd.factorize(x)
    out[x.name] = len(b)
    return a

b = df.apply(f)
print (b)
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1
2  2  1  2
3  3  2  3
4  4  3  4

a = pd.Series(out)
print (a)
0    5
1    4
2    5
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks, it is faster.

Answer (score 3):

#### with `pd.factorize`

The point of this is to capture the both out puts of `factorize` and use them in the integer encoding as well as the `nunique` calculation without having to `factorize` twice.

Run this to get encoding and unique values

```
e, u = zip(*map(pd.factorize, map(df.get, df)))
```

---

Turn encoding into dataframe

```
pd.DataFrame([*zip(*e)], df.index, df.columns)

   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  1
2  2  1  2
3  3  2  3
4  4  3  4
```

---

Turn length of unique values into a series

```
pd.Series([*map(len, u)], df.columns)

0    5
1    4
2    5
dtype: int64
```

---

All together, the assignment of the two objects is

```
e, u = zip(*map(pd.factorize, map(df.get, df)))    
df_ = pd.DataFrame([*zip(*e)], df.index, df.columns)
c = pd.Series([*map(len, u)], df.columns)
```

For those stuck with legacy Python, without the `[*it]` syntax

```
e, u = zip(*map(pd.factorize, map(df.get, df)))
df_ = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*e)), df.index, df.columns)
c = pd.Series(list(map(len, u)), df.columns)
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. However, *zip seems to be giving a ```invalid syntax``` error. Is it a python3 thing? I'm using python 2.7. Probably should've mentioned it sooner.

Answer (score 3):

I think using `list` `map` is good enough

```
l=list(map(set,df.values.T))
l
Out[71]: 
[{'i', 'j', 'o', 'v', 'y'},
 {'iw', 'jj', 'vf', 'yk'},
 {'iwd', 'jjy', 'ovg', 'vfs', 'yku'}]

list(map(len,l))
Out[74]: [5, 4, 5]
```

---

Usage of `np.unique`

```
def yourfunc(x):
    _,indices = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True)
    return indices
df.apply(yourfunc)
Out[102]: 
   0  1  2
0  2  1  2
1  1  1  1
2  4  3  4
3  3  2  3
4  0  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your approach seems to be 3X faster. See the timing results.

Comment: You can duplicate my solution with `np.uniuqe` by using this to assign `e` and `u`: `u, e = zip(*map(lambda x: np.unique(x, return_inverse=True), map(df.get, df)))`.  Keep in mind that `np.unique` is faster than `pd.factorize` for smaller arrays.  But as the size of the array increases, it becomes slower do to the fact that `np.unique` sorts and `pd.factorize` does not.  Another consequence of this is that the integer encodings of `np.unique` are in the order of the sorted unique values while `pd.factorize` is in the order of when they first appear. @NiloySaha

Comment: Hm, you are correct. However, jezrael's answer seems to scale even better.